# converting to mysqli - mysql_result - expects parameter 2 to be integer

Tags: php, mysqli

I have read all the questions regarding converting to mysqli, but cannot convert this code:

```
// Select how many news should be displayed
if ($u_rank >= 1) {
$sql = mysqli_query($connect_db, "SELECT news_d FROM users_data WHERE uid = '$id'");
$news_d = mysql_result($sql, news_d);
} else {
$news_d = 10;
};
```

If i try with the custom function:

```
function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) { 
$res->data_seek($row); 
$datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
return $datarow[$field]; 
}
```

And try to use in my code:

```
$news_d = mysqli_result($sql, news_d);
```

I got this error:
Warning: mysqli_data_seek() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given

Help would be appreciated,

Best, Misko

Comment: You made a typo and forgot the `$` in front of the `news_d` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your real code is the same as the one you posted in the question then there is an obvious problem in the line:

```
$news_d = mysqli_result($sql, news_d);
```

`news_d` is not `$news_d`. It looks like a constant (because it doesn't start with `$`) and it is interpreted as a constant. Because there is no constant named `news_d`, the interpreter converts it to a string. It is the same as:

```
$news_d = mysqli_result($sql, 'news_d');
```

The behaviour is explained in the PHP documentation page of [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php):

> If you use an undefined constant, PHP assumes that you mean the name of the constant itself, just as if you called it as a [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) (`CONSTANT` vs. `"CONSTANT"`). An error of level `E_NOTICE` will be issued when this happens. See also the manual entry on why [`$foo[bar]`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar) is wrong (unless you first [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) *bar* as a constant).

---

Since the `mysqli_result()` function passes its second argument to [`mysqli::data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) (`$res->data_seek($row);`), it must be a number, not a string. Unfortunately the purpose of the code you posted is not clear at all. Only you know what number you should pass to `mysqli_result()` as its first argument and why.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `news_d` which is invalid. This should be an integer. Try passing `0` instead, like so:

```
$news_d = mysqli_result($sql, 0);
```

Comment: Grrr...searching all day for this :(

Comment: You can also pass `$news_d` - but I can't see where that's referenced above the code block you've produced :(